# RedirectedThreadFrame in Callstack

Tags: .net, clr, windbg

Has anyone seen a RedirectedThreadFrame in a callstack in windbg? That is from the managed callstack. I am seeing alot of exceptions being thrown inside the framework that I am never seeing bubbled to me and I am trying to figure out why. The native callstack just has:

> 0526f6b0 79f63d27 KERNEL32!RaiseException+0x53
>   0526f718 79f64102 mscorwks!Thread::RedirectedHandledJITCase+0x198
>   0526f720 00000000 mscorwks!Thread::RedirectedHandledJITCaseForGCThreadControl+0x7

The managed callstack has:

> 0526f6dc 7c812aeb [RedirectedThreadFrame: 0526f6dc] 
>   0526f724 00c741b9 Library.Class.b__3(MyObject)
>   0526f7cc 00c73c85 ParallelProcessingLibrary.ActionController`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].ExecutePartition(System.Object)
>   0526f840 79a00eee System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
>   0526f84c 792e019f System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>   0526f864 797db48a System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)
>   0526fa8c 79e71b4c [GCFrame: 0526fa8c]

I have been unable to turn up any information as to what this means. Any explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this. This is occuring as the CLR suspends threads for the GC.
[Junfeng Zhang's Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2007/07/16/unknown-exception-0xe0434f4e.aspx)